# Failing write/read on RH850 with NOR flash

Tags: flash, freertos, mcu, nor, renesas-rx

Working Setup
Controller: RH850 F1KM-S4 (R7f701645)
IDE: CS+
Compiler : CC-RH
OS: FreeRTOS
Peripherals : CAN, UART,SPI.

Currently, we are interfacing NOR flash (25LP-WP256E) with RH850 via SPI., We are able to read the Chip ID and able to execute the commands like CHIP erase, Write enable etc., However , Page read and Page write are not happening successfully. When we try to write some data (say “HELLO”), driver returns MD_OK, but when we read the same page, It is reading only 0xFF,OxFF.... Hence we are unable to create Filesystem on this NOR flash.